# Sticky footer when using flex

Tags: html, css, responsive, sticky-footer

I am trying to make a responsive website with a sticky footer. So far I have been able to achieve what I want with the following HTML and CSS up until the point if anything inside content expands the div, for example if there are several more products, the footer will float over the top of the content div. What I am trying to achieve is for the footer to keep getting pushed down by the content above it.

I've tried using margin 0 auto on the wrapper div which uses flex instead, however it doesn't seem to achieve the results I am looking for.

Can someone help me unblock myself, or advice what I should actually be doing?

Thank you

```css
/* Desktop */

@media (max-width: 1480px) {
  .content,
  .header,
  .footer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 20px;
  }
  .border {
    display: none;
  }
  .product {
    width: 33.33% !important;
  }
}


/* Tablet */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header,
  .footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .product {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}


/* Mobile */

@media (max-width: 360px) {}


/* Main */

.push {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header,
.content,
.footer {
  width: 1380px;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.content {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.border {
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}

.product {
  width: 280px;
  height: 519px;
  float: left;
  background: fuchsia;
}

.footer {
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  background: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="push">

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="border"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="border"></div>
        <div class="product"></div>
        <div class="product"></div>
        <div class="product"></div>
        <div class="product"></div>
        <div class="border"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Updated:**
`position: sticky;` won't do, since you need to have footer always on the bot part of the page no matter the height of the content. So, we get to *plan B* which is `position: fixed;` with `bottom: 0;` and `width: 100%;`, which makes footer be full-width fixed on bottom **but** without taking any actual space.
In order to make this work, you need to add a `margin-bottom` on the `content` div with the height of your footer. In that way, you "fake" the existence of footer, therefore displaying the whole content of `content`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  min-height: 60px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Insert the height of your footer element (mine is 60px) */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.product {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ccc, #ccc5);
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 60px;
  background: #252525;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h2>This is the header.</h2>
  </header>
  <section class="content">
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <h2>This is the footer</h2>
    <div class="info">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="info">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="info">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your detailed reply. When I run your code snippet, then open in full page the footer isn't sticking to the bottom. Any ideas?

Comment: @Welly123456 actually my previous comment won't do. You're going to need `position: fixed;` for that. I'll update my answer with that approach in a while.

Comment: Hey George, I really aprichiate you taking your time out to try and fix this for me. I tried the position fixed as mentioned but it wasnt quite what i was looking for. I've added my solution to my original comment.

Answer (score 1):

try this approach:

```
style {
    .flex-body {
        display:flex;
        width:100%;
        height:100%; /* or use 100vh */
    }
    .flex-body .body {
        flex-grow:1;
        position:relative;
    }
    .flex-body .body .container {
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        overflow-y:auto;
    }
    .flex-body .footer {
        /* add footer styles here */
    }
}
```

and inside your `<body>` tag:

```
<div class="flex-body">
    <div class="body">
        <div class="container"><!-- contents of container --></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"><!-- contents of footer --></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <head>
<style>
  /* Desktop */
  @media (max-width: 1480px) {
    .main-wrapper, .content, .header, .footer {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
    .border {
      display: none;
    }
    .product {
      width: 33.33% !important;
    }
  }
  /* Tablet */
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .product {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
  /* Mobile */
  @media (max-width: 360px) {
  }
  /* Main */
  body {
    position: relative;
  }

  .main-wrapper, .header, .content, .footer {
    width: 1380px;
  }

  .main-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .footer-wrapper {
    clear: both;
    height: 180px;
    margin-top: -180px;
  }

  .header {
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
  }

  .content {
    background: blue;
  }

  .footer {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: greenyellow;
  }

  .border {
    width: 130px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: rebeccapurple;
  }

  .product {
    width: 280px;
    height: 519px;
    float: left;
    background: fuchsia;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <div class="product">
      </div>
      <div class="product">
      </div>
      <div class="product">
      </div>
      <div class="product">
      </div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-wrapper">
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="border"></div>
      <div class="border"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This solution is depending on setting `width` all the time and, imo, it will ruin your experience in the long term. Furthermore, it's bloated with things that are not working, like the elements with `.border`. Also, since you add `divs` with width percentages, it will force you to nest more `divs` inside divs, known as [divitis](https://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/faqs/what-is-divitis/).